# Do I really need to call QFile::close() in this case?

Tags: qt4

I'm not sure about QFile's behavior,

```
bool Class::Function (const QString & name)
{
  QFile fp (name);
  if (fp.open (QIODevice::ReadOnly))
  {
     // read file
     return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Hmm, it's not like a FILE* pointer in C (which you must close and free), would this be a problem if I don't call QFile::close() (Does it do automatically on destruction) ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`QFile` object is closed automatically ([Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfile.html#dtor.QFile)) upon its destructor; hence there is no need to call `close()` explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer calling fp.close() before the function returns: This may not be necessary but may not be harmful either.

The Qt documentation may not reflect the actual code. For example, following is the source code in Qt 5.5.0:

```
/*!
    Destroys the file object, closing it if necessary.
*/
QFile::~QFile()
{
}
```

So `QFile::close()` is not automatically called in the destructor. The documentation may need to be updated.

As an added advantage, Matching QFile::open() with QFile::close() will ensure that the file can be properly opened again the next time function `bool Class::Function()` is called.

Comment: `QFile` inherits `QFileDevice` which indeed calls `QFileDevice::close()` in  its destructor.

Comment: You are right. I forgot checking `QFile` class's inheritance chain. So there is no need to call the close() function in this case. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Now I see one more disadvantage of using inheritance: The documentation has to be replicated to its derived classes, as in the case of `QFileDevice` -> `QFile`. I'm not sure if there is a better way of ducumenting a same feature among all the classes in an inheritance chain.

Comment: Some documentation tools support special commands that insert the superclass documentation into the derived class documentation. If adding an inheritance chain to the docs in addition to the main code is "a better way" is questionable.