# Does QFile.open() behave like Python's with open() in terms of context management?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, with-statement, qfile

The Qt4.8 documentation (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12936267/4720018)) suggests that a QtCore.QFile-object closes its file upon destruction (if the file is open).

Does that mean that this PyQt4 snippet

```
my_file = QtCore.QFile('some_file.bin')
my_file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
... do stuff that might raise an exception ...
```

is similar to this non-PyQt snippet, which uses `open()` as context manager?

```
with open('some_file.bin', 'rb') as my_file:
   ... do stuff that might raise an exception ...
```

That is, in terms of the file being closed automatically when something goes wrong and the program exits (as discussed e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17584476/4720018)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A `QFile` will not be closed automatically if an error occurs. And in fact, there will be no exception raised either. Qt just doesn't do exceptions at all, so you will need to check return values and query the `error()` method instead.

Here's some example output:

```
>>> f = QtCore.QFile('/tmp/test.txt')
>>> f.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadWrite)
True
>>> f.resize(10)
True
```

Note how Qt just returns `True/False` here, whereas Python would raise an `OSError/IOError` if a problem had occurred.

```
>>> f.readAll()
PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
>>> f.error() == QtCore.QFile.NoError
True
```

An explicit check was required here to make sure no error occured when reading.

```
>>> f.close()
>>> f.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
True
>>> f.resize(20)
False
>>> f.error() == QtCore.QFile.ResizeError
True
```

So now an error as been induced - but no exception is raised, and the file is still open and readable:

```
>>> f.isOpen()
True
>>> f.readAll()
PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
>>> f.error() == QtCore.QFile.NoError
True
```

Deleting a `QFile` will automatically close it; but otherwise, you will need to explicitly close it to free up resources - even if errors occurred during its lifetime.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer and nice examples. One more thing: Suppose, after QFile.open(), I do something, unrelated to the file, that _does_ raise an exception, which is not caught and causes the program to exit. In that case I guess the QFile will be deleted, so the file _will_ be closed automatically?

Comment: @Dennis. It depends whether there are still references held for the `QFile`. If there's anything keeping it alive, an exception *per se* won't result in it automatically being closed. But of course, if the program exits, it will be deleted eventually.